# switch order of blog posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, blogs

I need my blog posts to display the opposite way. post 1 should be underneath post 2, etc.

This is my code which loops through the posts & renders them:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div>
    <div><%= post.name %></div>
    <div><%= post.title %></div>
    <div><%= post.content %></div>
    <div><%= link_to 'Show', post %></div>
    <div><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></div>
    <div><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort them before assigning them to `@posts` in the controller ...

in rails 3:

```
@posts = Posts.order('id DESC')
```

The benefit here is with a little work you can also sort by other columns too...

Comment: where exactly in the controller should I sort them?

Comment: you would replace @posts = Posts.all in the def index I believe if that's where you are displaying them from.

Answer (score 2):

You could throw a `reverse` in there:

```
<% @posts.reverse.each do |post| %>
```

I'm guessing that you don't want to reverse the whole sort order because you have some pagination involved and that you want the over all order as it already is.